# setting different title of button based on web-response in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am a beginner with objective-c. Searched a lot but didn't get my issue solve. I have a cell prototype in tableview, which has multiple label and a button. Button would be inactive and active based on the server side data. For example if `feedback = close`, the button will be inactive and only show the text close and if `feedback = action`, the button will show an image which is set in the storyboard during cell prototyping. Some action will be performed on the button click. My problem is, first time my tableview show the data as expected, but on scrolling button images are getting `changed to the text close`. Here is my code. Adding screenshot for clarity. I have to perform two different action on button click and row click.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Ko6.png)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

TransactionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customTransactionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[TransactionCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"customTransactionCell"];
} 
// Configure the cell.

if([[[transactionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"Close"]){
    [cell.feedbackButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.feedbackButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

}
else
    if([[[transactionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"Open"])
    {
        [cell.feedbackButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.feedbackButton setTitle:@"Open" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];     
    }
else
 {
 cell.feedbackButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.feedbackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(feedbackButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your implementation. Let me describe one by one & try to fix them

**Issue 1**

In the last else you are adding `target selector` using following code segment

```
 [cell.feedbackButton addTarget:self      action:@selector(feedbackButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

UITableView is designed to re-use the same cell to display another set of data, So every time this `else` is executed same action is added multiple times. You can declare the target in the implementation of the `TransactionCell` just once when `awakeFromNib` or any other `init` method like `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`. That is how one button will cause react only once when it's being pressed once.

Your `TransactionCell.m` should look like following

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
          reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)id
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:id];
    if(self)
    {
               [self.feedbackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(feedbackButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)feedbackButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    //do your feedback action according to your data
}
```

if you're using nib / storyboard, then no need to manually the `addTarget` in the `initWithStyle: reusingIdentifier:`, just add the `IBAction` from the nib / storyboard to your target action using assistant view of the xcode & insepector pane.

**Issue 2**

You are setting the state of the button for the state only you needed, without caring the other states. here are the responsible code portion

```
if([[[transactionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"Close"]){
[cell.feedbackButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.feedbackButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

}
else
    if([[[transactionList   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"action"]isEqualToString:@"Open"])
{
    [cell.feedbackButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.feedbackButton setTitle:@"Open" forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];     
}
```

You should specify the state of the button like following

```
if(/* open case */)
{
    cell.feedbackButton.enabled = NO;
    //other configuration like title / image 
}
else if(/*close case*/)
{
    cell.feedbackButton.enabled = NO;
    //other configuration like title / image
}
else if(/* feedback case */)
{
    cell.feedbackButton.enabled = YES;
    //other configuration like title / image
}
```

Never try to stop re-using the same cell by creating new cell for every data. It will cause larger memory traces other than re-using the same `UITableViewCell`.

Happy coding.

Comment: I'll try and let u know if any issue comes.

Comment: please check the update. If I use issue 2 suggestion, my whole row get clickable.

Comment: then use `tableView.allowsSelection = NO;` so that the whole row is not clickable.

Comment: Okay, thats not the issue. The main issue is, reusable cell. I tried your first issue suggestion, but its giving error. Can't I Show button with indexPath.row?

Comment: `The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'` Should Ihave to `return self;`

Comment: my bad, i forgot to put the `self =`  & `return` the `self`. i have edited the code

Comment: Still getting reused :(

Comment: seems like I have two use two protoype cell

Comment: come on, it's meant to be reused, you need to clear things up. plz share the problem you are facing now.

Comment: can we chat somewhere, my reputation is too low to move into chat section.

Comment: hope you can accept the answer now, which solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Your cells are being reused, this means cell after reuse will save all the settings you've set to it during last use. This means in last else (`action:@selector(feedbackButtonClick:)`) the cell will not change visual settings inherited during last use of the cell. You must nor reset the cell (better by overriding `-[TransactionCell prepareForReuse]`) or set up visuals for each case of your logic without possibility to skip previous design setup.
Well there is no example for your specific case as i don't know your default UI settings, but it will be something like

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
  [super prepareForReuse];
  [self.feedbackButton setImage:<DEFAULT IMAGE> forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [cell.feedbackButton setTitle:<DEFAULT TITLE> forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
  [cell.feedbackButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents]; 
}
```

Comment: i understand the explanation, but can u please post some example to override `-[TransactionCell prepareForReuse]` and what do u mean by visuals for each case?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the way UITableView is designed to reuse cells. When your code dequeues a reusable cell, it will still be in the state it was configured to when you last used that cell.

You should manually set the image within your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" before evaluating the "transactionList".

**Even Better**
I would suggest you create a cell reset function you could message at the beginning of your "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {

        TransactionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customTransactionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell==nil)
        {
            cell = [[TransactionCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"customTransactionCell"];
        } 
        // Configure the cell.

        [self resetCell:cell];

        ...

    }

    -(void)resetCell:(TransactionCell *)cell
    {
        //reset any variables you may have changed from the reused cell
        [cell. feedbackButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Comment: i'll try resetting the cell.